# Aliasing objects from expensive statements in Scala pattern match

Tags: scala

I have an expensive case statement which needs to hit the database to determine a *complete match*. If there is a match, the result from the aforementioned call must be used to perform further operations:

```
def intent = {
    case request @ GET(Path(Seg(database :: Nil))) if recordsFrom(database) != Nil =>
        renderOutput(recordsFrom(database))
    case ...
}
```

I would like to call `recordsFrom(database)` only once. In the above example, it is called twice. It seems like I should be able to apply some alias to the statement?

Answer (score 4):

Lawrence, from what I'm seeing you're using Unfiltered to handle a RESTful request but you've also combined a database lookup with that response filtering. I would advise you not to do that. Instead I'd arrange things as following:

```
val dbReqCommand = new DBRequestCommand(myDbConPool)

def intent ={
  case req @ GET(Path(Seq(database :: Nil))) => dbReqCommand(req, database)
}
```

Wherein you've encapsulated the db requests in an object that you could substitute out for testing purposes (think integration tests without a DB backend.) Within the request handler you might then put in the response:

```
Option(recordsFrom(database)) match{
  case Some(value) => OK ~> renderOpupt(value)
  case None => //an error response or Pass
}
```

That way you might have something along the lines of:

```
trait DBReqPlan{
  def dbReqCommand: RequestCommand[String]

  def intent ={
   case req @ GET(Path(Seq(database :: Nil))) => dbReqCommand(req, database)
  }
}
```

which is easier to test against and work with.

Comment: Thanks for the unfiltered advice :) from these answers it seems Scala doesn't provide a mechanism for applying aliases to expensive object creations within pattern match cases.  I guess this is the exact reason that unfiltered introduced Pass (i.e. to relinquish a match subsequent to invoking more advanced logic)... seems like a generic requirement though...

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield Well, that's not completely true. You could create your own item with it's own `unapply` which you then pattern match over. I've done it before atop of Unfiltered which I dubbed "routes." Then you could have access to a number of things. That said, it's still fairly bad practice to have DB access as part of your routing. Authentication can be handled within the response objects and what not.

Comment: Ah brilliant idea (for other use cases)!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
def intent = {
  case request @ GET(Path(Seg(database :: Nil))) =>
    val records = recordsFrom(database) 
    if(!records.isEmpty){ 
      renderOutput(records)
    } else {
      ...
    }
  case ...
```

You can move the body of the first case to a different function if you want to avoid having too many nested blocks.

Comment: This will cause a match when the database does not contain records. Maybe fine for the contrived example, but produces a very different behaviour for the resulting partial function.

Comment: So what? You match on your request, use the database to retrieve a list of records and then test to see if the list is empty or not, you can handle both cases in an if statement. Pattern matching is cool, but it's not the answer to every problem.